# Echo a variable without executing possible malicious code in a Bash CGI binary

Tags: html, forms, bash, variables

I'm working on a BASH CGI Binary that reads a string a user would type from an HTML form, then appends that string to a log file on my Linux server. I'm using BASH.cgi as seen on (http://oinkzwurgl.org/bash_cgi) to transfer all the POST/GET input user strings automatically into variables. Everything is working perfectly fine, however I found a major security flaw:

HTML Form...

```
        <form action="?" method="POST">
            Feedback:<textarea name="comments"></textarea>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

BASH CGI...

```
        echo "$comments" >> ./logs/log.txt
```

Suppose a malicious user would submit the following into the comments text area of the form:

```
        $( rm -rf / )
```

BASH.cgi would then create a new variable called "comments" that returns the executed value of everything in between the $( and the ). This would in result compromise the server by executing anything a malicious user would please. There must be a way to directly and safely pass the string of a variable without executing what's inside. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

-- Egoscio

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've identified is a vulnerability in Bash.CGI itself — it is failing to properly filter out `$(` in variables.

**Do not use Bash.CGI. It is insecure.** Beyond the issue you have identified, a number of other serious vulnerabilities exist in this script, some of which are listed below. I would highly recommend that you use another, more appropriate scripting language, such as Perl, Python, or PHP.

---

Bonus vulnerabilities:

- Every variable present in a GET or POST query is imported into a variable, including variables that have special significance to the shell (e.g, PATH) and ones which were part of the CGI environment (e.g, REMOTE_USER, as noted in the documentation).
- The name of a variable is not filtered at all. Variable names containing special characters may cause unexpected behavior.
- Probably more. **Again, this script is insecure. Do not use it.**

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast! I was hoping there was a possibility to  safely utilize BASH to make web apps, however I never took in consideration the rest of the security problems that you have mentioned. I will try learning PHP instead. Another question, is bashlib any safer? Thanks again.

Comment: I haven't looked at bashlib; that being said, shell scripts are not a well-suited language for writing CGI scripts in general.